# USB serial port driver

Tags: linux, drivers, development

Writing new driver for wp7607 base on GobiSerial and qcserial.
I only defined the init(), exit() and probe() functions but I can still use the AT command with just such a simple driver.

How can the AT command work with only the above 3 functions defined ?

Is usbserial(core) driver doing that job?.
If it can, then could anyone explain the processing of the send/receive data flow between PC and module through the usb serial port driver?